# adl failing silently

Tags: flash, air

I am running adl via the following, in Terminal on Mac, 10.8.2 :

`/path/to/sdk/bin/adl -runtime path/to/sdk/runtimes/air/mac path/to/theApp-app.xml`

And... nothing happens. Nothing launches, the command line simply gives me the next prompt, no error messages are added to console.

This only began happening in the last few days - I have updated Air during that time, but unfortunately can't swear that the problem coincided with that because of the gap since I last ran this task.

My Air SDK is 3.5.

I've confirmed that the first 2 paths are correct by the fact that if I change either of them then I get an appropriate error message in the command line. The final argument (the app descriptor) appears to be being ignored at the moment (if I change it to a path that does not exist there is no error) which leads me to think that the xml inside that app descriptor is not the culprit.

I've deleted adl.plist and com.adobe.adl.plist from my library. mm.cfg contains nothing interesting.

I have also (just to see) tried launching with -nodebug but that makes no difference.

The app is a Desktop application.

Edit: I just tried launch a different Air app with the same (silent) result.

Further Edit: The exit code (obtained from echo $?) is 1. Which is equivalent to `Successful invocation of an already running AIR application. ADL exits immediately.`

Exiting immediately is certainly what I'm seeing. So, it seems to be incorrectly finding that the Air app is already running. I've tried restarting, and the first run after restart is no different.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded a new copy of the SDK and dropped it into a fresh location, and that is working fine.

I can't verify it but I think the permissions of the enclosing folder were to blame.